# Matching certain value in JSON Array using match() or find() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm looking for a function or method to overcome this issue
Here is the JSON Array

```
[{
    "type": "radar",
    "detail": [{
        "subject": "sub1"
    }, {
        "subject": "sub2"
    }]
}, {
    "type": "bar",
    "detail": [{
        "subject": "sub1"
    }, {
        "subject": "sub2"
    }]
}]
```

I'm hoping to identify the value of "type" which in this case would be "radar" and "bar"，and match with the variable x。 
Here's the code:

```
for(x in myarray)
{
    if(myarray[x]['type']=="bar")
    {
        console.log("equal");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("no result");
    }
}
```

With this code,the result on the website console would be both "equal" and "no result",while I wish to print "equal" only.I understand the logic error in this code,but I couldn't figure out the correct way to fix it.

Comment: Remove the else condition ?

Comment: note: that's an array, there's nothing JSON about it once a JSON String (which is redundant, because JSON is a string by deifinition) has been parsed - as in this case

Comment: look at using `Array#some` or `Array#find` method

Comment: I simplified the original code,which need to preserve the else condition,that is why I'm looking for some suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.some` for this which return `true` or `false` if one of the array element match with `type` "bar" then It will return `true` otherwise `false`

```js
var data = [{
    "type": "radar",
    "detail": [{
        "subject": "sub1"
    }, {
        "subject": "sub2"
    }]
}, {
    "type": "bar",
    "detail": [{
        "subject": "sub1"
    }, {
        "subject": "sub2"
    }]
}]

if (data.some(val => val.type == "bar"))
    console.log("Equal")
else
    console.log("No record found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `for` loop runs for each object in the array, the first console log for `equal` is for matched type and second console log is for the unmatched type. So, to get only one console and to write more appropriate code, you can use `Array.find()` and then add a `if-else` block for that. Something like this:

```js
var myarray = [ { "type":"radar", "detail": [{ "subject":"sub1" }, { "subject":"sub2" }] }, { "type":"bar", "detail": [{ "subject":"sub1" }, { "subject":"sub2" }] } ];

var match = myarray.find(({type}) => type === "bar");
if(match) {
  console.log("equal");
} else {
   console.log("no result");
}
```

Comment: I found it always print "equal" even if I change "bar" to any other irrelative noun

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myArr = [ 
  { "type":"radar", 
   "detail": [
     { "subject":"sub1" }, 
     { "subject":"sub2" }
   ] 
  }, 
  { "type":"bar",
   "detail": [
     { "subject":"sub1" }, 
     { "subject":"sub2" }
   ] 
  } 
]

for(let x of myArr){
  if(x.type === 'bar'){ console.log('equal')}
  else { console.log('no result')}
}
```

In order to understand what went wrong with your code, first when you have a `for` loop, you need to have a `let/var` keyword as below:

```
for(let x of myArr)
```

Secondly, instead of using `for..in` loop, which it meant for looping property of objects, use `for..of` loop which meant for looping array.

Third, while looping `myArr`, each and every element `x` is an object and type is the property, so just use `x.type` to make the comparison.

Lastly, as others have mentioned, Array#some / Array#find is a better way to deal with finding existence of element in an array

Comment: Thanks for the advise,I'll pay more effort on it